# Matrix multiplication issue (shapes not alligned)

Tags: neural-network, rnn, numpy, implementation

I am building an RNN using numpy only and have started on the forward propagation section. However i am having some issues aligning my matrices. The issue is on this line:

```
h = np.dot(u, x) + np.dot(aprev, w) + bh
```

More specifically, the problem is with this part:

```
np.dot(u, x)
```

I tried playing around with it by transposing different parts but I still receive the error:

```
ValueError: shapes (8,8) and (4,8) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

How can i overcome this? The entirety of my code is pasted below, and note that at the beginning i transposed x, to make data entry and inserting data into its corresponding timestep easy. '.T' can be easy to miss sometimes.

```
import numpy as np

# Data Processing

x = np.array([
    # t/no. of inputs         
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],     # Samples
    [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
    [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]).T

# Model Parameters

numInputs = x.shape[1]
timeSteps = x.shape[0]
numNeurons = 8

u = np.random.random((numNeurons, numInputs))
v = np.random.random((numInputs, numNeurons))
w = np.random.random((numNeurons, numNeurons))
bh = np.zeros((numNeurons, 1))
bo = np.zeros((numInputs, 1))
aprev = 0

# Training

def fprop(x, aprev, u, v, w, bh, bo):
    h = np.dot(u, x) + np.dot(aprev, w) + bh
    a = np.tanh(h)
    o = np.dot(a, v) + bo
    yhat = (np.exp(o))/(np.sum(np.exp(o)))
    aprev = a

for t in x:
    fprop(t, aprev, u, v, w, bh, bo)
```

Comment: Are you familiar to matrix multiplication?

Comment: @Media I have been using dot product because I’ve seen it being used in many other examples. Does matrix multiplication do the same thing and overcome my problem as well?

Comment: It depends on your task, do you want to have matrix multiplication? For matrix multiplication your dimensions must match.

Comment: @Media i don’t mind, as long as it solves the issue and doesn’t affect forward prop/backprop, or the results of my network

Comment: @Media it didn’t work, it reported the same issue

Comment: I guess you are not familiar with the concept of vectorization, it does matter depending on your task.

Comment: @Media how could I align the matrices in the above code?

Comment: I don't know what is the task of your rnn, but I highly recommend you use tensorflow which calculates the backward path for you.

Comment: @Media it’s a toy data set. I’m learning how to program an RNN from scratch, so I need to stay away from automatic libraries like tensorflow

Comment: How does the original formula look like for `h = np.dot(u, x) + np.dot(aprev, w) + bh`?

Comment: St = tanh(UXt + WSt-1 + bh). I’ve actually solved the problem in the meantime, haha. If you wanted to know, I replaced ‘np.dot(u, x)’ with ‘x.dot(u)’, and replaced ‘o = np.dot(a, v)’ with ‘o = np.dot(a, v.T)’ respectively. I know why transposing v solved the problem, but no idea why changing the operation solved the first. I thought np.dot(a, b) and a.dot(b) were the same, but clearly not! At least it’s fixed @keiv.fly

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you for your help @Media. The solution is above

Comment: You changes the order from u,x to x,u which are completely different operations. np.dot(a,b) should be the same as a.dot(b), but not b.dot(a)